# How to get Shellhub.io working on old CPU

Tags: docker, shell, avx

After installing shellhub and starting the the containers using docker-compse i got the error message on the console

```
c./bin/docker-compose up
shellhub_mongo_1 is up-to-date
shellhub_ssh_1 is up-to-date
shellhub_api_1 is up-to-date
shellhub_ui_1 is up-to-date
Starting shellhub_gateway_1 ... done
Attaching to shellhub_mongo_1, shellhub_ssh_1, shellhub_api_1, shellhub_ui_1, shellhub_gateway_1
api_1      |
api_1      |    ____    __
api_1      |   / __/___/ /  ___
api_1      |  / _// __/ _ \/ _ \
api_1      | /___/\__/_//_/\___/ v3.3.10-dev
api_1      | High performance, minimalist Go web framework
api_1      | https://echo.labstack.com
api_1      | ____________________________________O/_______
api_1      |                                     O\
api_1      | ⇨ http server started on [::]:8080
mongo_1    | 2021-02-24T14:48:50.370+0000 I  COMMAND  [conn3] CMD: dropIndexes main.users: "tenant_id"
mongo_1    | 2021-02-24T14:48:50.403+0000 I  COMMAND  [conn3] CMD: dropIndexes main.users: "session_record"
mongo_1    | 2021-02-24T14:53:32.846+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
shellhub_gateway_1 exited with code 132
shellhub_gateway_1 exited with code 132
shellhub_gateway_1 exited with code 132
```

It seems that shellhub_gateway use  AVX(Advanced Vector Extensions) which is not supported on my old intel atom CPU.

Any idea how to get shellhub work on old CPUs ?

Comment: CPU Detail : Model name: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N2800 @ 1.86GHz

Comment: i have opened an issue on GitHub : https://github.com/shellhub-io/shellhub/issues/737 technical team are working to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by Shellhub core team bellow quoted their response:

Looks good, no errors.

It seems it's fixed in [8a14707](https://github.com/shellhub-io/shellhub/commit/8a147071e21cbd47d6bcf86827a1f9286d184f0d).

You can create a docker-compose.override.yml with following config to workaround the issue until we release next version with a fix:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  gateway:
    ports:
      - "${SHELLHUB_HTTP_PORT}:80"
```